# flash[:notice] doesn't work with redirect_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using from controller status:

```
  flash[:notice] = 'message'
  redirect_to(controller: 'item', action: 'list')
```

I don't know why the notice don't show up.

I tried and checked many things:

1. `flash.keep`
2. `flash.keep[:notice] = 'message'`
3. `flash[:notice]` works fine with `render`
4. `redirect_to(controller: 'item', action: 'list',  notice: 'message')`
5. `flash.now[:notice] = "Hello world"`
6. `flash.now['foo'] = "Hello world"` with `<%= flash['foo'] %>` in the view
7. There is a <%= flash[:notice] %> in the layout

I put the following code to in the layout. flash[:notice] work fine when I the controller method have a view with the same name. The problem happens when I try to reach another controller which don't have a view.

```
<% if !flash[:notice].blank? %>
    <div class="notice">
        <%= flash[:notice] %>
    </div>
<% end %>

<% if !flash[:alert].blank? %>
    <div class="alert">
        <%= flash[:alert] %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

Can anyone help?

Info:

- Ruby (2.0.0)
- Rails (3.2.13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea about what happened.

I updated to ruby 2.0.0 and it just started to work again...

Answer (score 5):

Railsguide: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-flash

This should work perfectly fine:

```
flash[:notice] = "My message"
redirect_to root_url
```

Or:

```
redirect_to root_url, notice: "Hello world"
```

However, it could also be possible you forgot to render notices in your view. Hence, you don't see any notices whatsoever.

For example, something like this should be in your view:

```
<% if flash[:notice] %>
  <p class="notice"><%= flash[:notice] %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is redirect_to(controller: 'item', action: 'list', notice: 'message') equal to: flash[:notice] = 'message'
  redirect_to(controller: 'item', action: 'list')?

Comment: The two examples I gave are the same, just with a different notation.

Comment: I did the first. Same problem... I'm considering using session for it... Do you think this problem can be because of my rails and ruby version? They are to updated.

Comment: I've heard Rails 3.2.13 is not entirely stable yet, so that could be a problem. Personally I use 3.2.12 with ruby 1.9.3 and I haven't encountered any errors. Anyway, are you sure you actually render the notices in your view?

Comment: Yes, I'm. It even works when I don't go to another controller.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
flash.now['foo'] = "Hello world"
```