# Rails 4- Flash messages are not showing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

After I am trying to display a flash message on my contact page. Here is my code

```
def contact_us
  UserMailer.delay.contact_email(params)
  flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for contacting us!!!!!'
  redirect_to contact_path
end

def contact
end
```

I tried to access the flash messages but getting a blank response.

```
[1] pry(#<#<Class:0x0000000aef74f0>>)> flash
=> #<ActionDispatch::Flash::FlashHash:0x0000000a633328 @discard=#<Set: {}>, @flashes={}, @now=nil>
```

Also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32010436) solution But getting same issue.
Can anyone have an idea why I am getting this issue?
How can I fix this issue.

Request details

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/contact

Completed 302 Found in 213ms (ActiveRecord: 46.9ms)
Started GET "/contact" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-23 01:08:43 +0530
```

**EDIT**
I also tried with

- Try1

  ```
  redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Thanks for contacting....'
  ```

  still getting the same issue.
- Try 2

`flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for contacting....'
 flash.keep(:notice)
 redirect_to contact_path`

still getting the same issue.

Tried all the solutions from [flash[:notice] doesn't work with redirect_to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15621364/flashnotice-doesnt-work-with-redirect-to) still getting the same error.

I am using ruby 2.0.0p643 and Rails 4.0.13.

Comment: what do your application logs say when you perform the request? i assume you are calling `contact_us` that get's redirected to `contact` which should display the flash message? would be helpful to put this into your question...

Comment: @phoet I have added my request details.

Comment: Try `flash.now[:notice] = "..."`

Comment: @DannyY Tried your solution still getting same issue.

Comment: If you can't solve this, try logging an issue against the Rails repository. Importantly, try to reproduce it on a new, empty Rails app, and make that one public as an example, link it in the issue. There might be a problem with rails itself.

Comment: Do you have it rendering in your layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same type of issue. When I checked the server log I got following error on the console

```
Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
```

For fixing this issue I have added following line the controller

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Following.

```
def contact_us
  UserMailer.delay.contact_email(params)
  redirect_to contact_path
  flash[:notice] = 'Thanks for contacting us!!!!!'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But this is not the correct way for specifying flash message.

Comment: @Natsu Try to move your flash message in `contact_email` action

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your application layout:

```
<%= flash[:notice] %>
```